# Converting tensorflow 2 estimator to tf.lite

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to convert an estimator `LinearClassifier` into tflite. 
However the code is throwing some error.. I am not able to understand where I am doing wrong.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

dftrain = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')
dfeval = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv')
y_train = dftrain.pop('survived')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('survived')

#create feature columns. For testing I am using only numeric ones
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['age', 'fare']

feature_columns = []

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name,
                                           dtype=tf.float32))

# Use entire batch since this is such a small dataset.
NUM_EXAMPLES = len(y_train)

def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    def input_fn():
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
        if shuffle:
          dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
        # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).
        dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
        # In memory training doesn't use batching.
        dataset = dataset.batch(NUM_EXAMPLES)
        return dataset
    return input_fn

# Training and evaluation input functions.
train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain[NUMERIC_COLUMNS], y_train)
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(dfeval[NUMERIC_COLUMNS], y_eval, shuffle=False, n_epochs=1)


linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns)

# Train model.
linear_est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)


# Evaluation.
result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
```

So model is working fine.

```
print(pd.Series(result))

accuracy                  0.659091
accuracy_baseline         0.625000
auc                       0.667095
auc_precision_recall      0.589936
average_loss              0.619227
label/mean                0.375000
loss                      0.619227
precision                 0.764706
prediction/mean           0.336755
recall                    0.131313
global_step             100.000000
dtype: float64
```

Now saving part:

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))
model_dir = 'model_data'
path = linear_est.export_saved_model(model_dir, serving_input_fn)
```

when I am using :

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(path)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

it throws error :

```
ValueError: This converter can only convert a single ConcreteFunction. Converting multiple functions is under development.
```

I have also tried :

```
saved_model_obj = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir=path)
concrete_func = saved_model_obj.signatures['serving_default']
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

And error is :

```
ConverterError: See console for info.
2020-02-18 16:23:15.446583: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:193] Unsupported data type in placeholder op: 20
2020-02-18 16:23:15.446687: F tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:2706] Check failed: status.ok() Input_content string_val doesn't have the right dimensions for this string tensor
     (while processing node 'head/AsString')
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following info:

> "Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard TensorFlow Lite runtime. If those are native TensorFlow operators, you might be able to use the extended runtime by passing --enable_select_tf_ops, or by setting target_ops=TFLITE_BUILTINS,SELECT_TF_OPS when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Otherwise, if you have a custom implementation for them you can disable this error with --allow_custom_ops, or by setting allow_custom_ops=True when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Here is a list of builtin operators you are using: ADD, ADD_N, ARG_MAX, EXPAND_DIMS, FULLY_CONNECTED, RESHAPE, SOFTMAX, TILE. Here is a list of operators for which **you will need custom implementations: As
> String."**

For me, this problem was solved after adding option "--allow_custom_ops":

```
tflite_convert --enable_v1_converter --allow_custom_ops --output_file=xxx --saved_model_dir=xxx --saved_model_signature_key='predict'
```